# Is there is possible to change the fontsize in the entire application from a viewmodel?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin.forms and I am using MVVM pattern. I have just built a settingspage and it is very simple. It has a ViewModel for the logic and a xaml file for the view.

In the view I got a picker with three different values 0: small, 1: medium, 2: large.

In the ViewModel,
I am wondering if its possible to change the fontsize on the entire application from the viewModel (settingsViewModel)?

Comment: Under normal circumstances, I can use a [Global Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/application) to apply a change to all elements in your App.

Comment: Any ideas on how to change the style on all pages with help of a picker? It  would require some logic on some VM. It's almost like overriding styles multiple time? @CherryBu-MSFT

Comment: If you want to change the entire application fontsize, you can use override **AttachBaseContext** method, but I can not know how to use picker to update fontsize.